# Application not working in android 9 Pie only showing black screen

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

My application is working except in android 9 Pie. I dont see any error on my app and everything works well. I havent find any explanation about this error.

My Application got an error when after i log in to application and then it shows nothing but a blank black layout. Do anyone ever get this kind of error? Please help me. Thanks.

**UPDATE 8/3/2019**

i've found the answer, it is caused by newest requirement on android pie which is device cannot send data to server HTTP without set apache.http.legacy into **andorid:required="false**.

Comment: We need code, logcats, etc. before we can answer your question.

Comment: this is the problem, i dont know what code that cause the error @KristyWelsh. Just wish there's someone who ever got this error

Comment: Send your logcat data

Comment: Print the code that is showing "black".

Comment: i'm installing my android pie avd to check it out

Comment: see my edited post

Comment: Hey @Iganov.Please check my answer.I got the same issue and i got rid of it.Its because we are using http instead of https for the Pie devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Recently had the same issue for Android 9, but I had to use some URLs for different screens. So I added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to Manifest and it worked, but we didn't want to compromise the security of the whole app for this. So the fix was in changing links from HTTP to https.But if you had to use only http to communicate with your app then here is your solution.

```
Add this in the Manifest file

android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/security_config"

Add this in the Xml
<network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"/>
<debug-overrides>
 <trust-anchors>
    <certificates src="system" />
    <certificates src="user" />
</trust-anchors>
</debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```